# On $\sum_{\rho\in D} \text{dist}(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial{D}}\log \zeta(s)\ ds$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

Let $D$ denote a closed two dimensional figure as: $D=2+iT\to 2\to 2-\delta\to 2-\delta+i(T-\delta)\to \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon+i(T-\delta)\to\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\to\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\to \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon+iT\to 2+iT$ where $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ and $T>3$.
Assume that the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$ is non zero on the boundary of $D$ and there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $\zeta(s)$ is non zero on and inside the $L-$ shaped region $L_\delta$, where $L_\delta=2+iT\to 2\to 2-\delta\to 2-\delta+i(T-\delta)\to \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon+i(T-\delta)\to\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon+iT\to 2+iT$ whenever $0<\delta<\delta_0$.

I need to apply Littlewood's lemma for $\zeta(s)$ in $D$.

> **Question:** How do we define logarithm for all points $s$ in $D$ so that we can apply Littlewood's lemma for $\zeta(s)$ in $D$. Note that $D$ is not a rectangle so normal definition of logarithm as in the usual Littlewood's lemma might not work.

I tried the following: **version of Littlewood's Lemma for $D$:** Let $D$ be defined as above and $\zeta(s)$ be a holomorphic function in $D$ not vanishing on the boundary of $D$. Then \begin{equation}\sum_{\rho\in D} \text{dist}(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial{D}}\log \zeta
 (s)\ ds \tag{1}\end{equation}
where in the above integral we go through $\partial{D}$ in negative direction (clockwise), $\rho$ are the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ inside $D$ counted with multiplicity, $\text{dist}(\rho)$ denotes the distance of $\rho$ to the left side of $D$ and $\log \zeta(s)$ is defined by continuous variation as follows: We start with a particular determination on $\sigma=2$, and obtain the value at other points of $D$ by continuous variation from $\log \zeta(2+it)$ down to $\log \zeta(2)$ and then left to (a point in between $2$ and $2-\delta$) $\log \zeta(2a+(2-\delta)(1-a))$ (where $0\leq a\leq 1$) then upwards to $\log \zeta((2a+(2-\delta)(1-a))+it')$ (where $t'=(T-\delta)b+T(1-b)$ where $0\leq b\leq 1$) then left to $\log \zeta\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)c+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)(1-c)+it'\right)$ (where $0\leq c\leq 1$) and then down to $\log \zeta(\sigma+it)$ till we reach $\sigma+it$. Mathematically we have for $s\in D$ and $A=2a+(2-\delta)(1-a)$ , $B=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\right)c+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)(1-c)$ \begin{align}\log \zeta(\sigma+it)&=\log \zeta(2+it)\notag\\&
 +\left(\int_{2+it}^{2}+\int_{2}^{A}+\int_{A}^{A+it'}+\int_{A+it'}^{B+it'}+\int_{B+it'}^{\sigma+it}\right) \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\ ds \tag{2}\end{align}
provided that $t$ and $t'$ are not the ordinate of zeros. If, however, this path would cross a zero or  pole of $\zeta(s)$, we take $\log \zeta(s)$ to be $\log \zeta(s\pm i0)$ according as we approach the path from above or below.

Does the definition of logarithm needs any changes?

Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but posting a wall of text with 12 (!) numbered equations and not much guide to what needs to be read to understand the question, and what is just background, definitely does encourage me to skip this question and move on to the next one.

Comment: A proof of the Littlewood lemma, which answers your question, may be found here:https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/ntandrmt/talks/MmtsAndZerosTalk_Gonek2.pdf

Comment: @Stopple Thanks. But in the link you gave we have Littlewood's lemma on a rectangle, but my $D$ is not a rectangle. So how do we define $\log \zeta(s)$ on $D$?

Comment: The same proof works.  You put little circles around all the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, with (two) line segments connecting each circle to the boundary of $D$ so $\log(\zeta(s))$ is well defined inside $D$ and outside the circles.  Any choice of the branch is fine.

Comment: @Stopple I mean can we define $\log \zeta(s)$ starting at the point $2+it$ to $2$ to $A$ to $A+it'$ to $B+it'$ to $\sigma+it$ when $t$ and $t'$ are not the ordinate of zero of $\zeta$. (At zeros we define by limiting process)?

Comment: Read the proof I linked.  You only need to define $\log$ away from the zeros.

Comment: @Stopple Thank you. I have read the proof earlier. In usual Littlewood's lemma on a rectangle we define log by starting with a particular determination on the line $\sigma=\sigma_2$ and then obtain the value at other points $s$ in the rectangle along $t=$ constant from $\log f(\sigma_2+it)$. If however this path crosses a zero or pole of $f(s)$ we define $\log f(s)$ to be $\log f(s\pm i 0)$. What will be the definition of $\log \zeta(s)$ by continuous variation in $D$?

Comment: @Stopple For the above definition please see Titchmarsh, Theory of Functions page $133$

Comment: See page 5 here: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9781786346148_0001

Comment: as mentioned in comments/answers to many similar posts here and on MSE, the definition you want to use works only if a form of RH is assumed, namely that there are no zeroes of zeta in the strip $1/2+ \epsilon < \sigma < 1$ up to height $t$; the crucial thing in the proof of Littlewood lemma is that $\log F$ is analytic on the domain obtained when you remove the zeroes inside and segments joining them to the corresponding rectangle side you want to measure their distance from, while in the Titchmarsh definition we take out ALL the left half lines starting at ALL zeroes in the critical strip

Comment: so in particular $\log F$ will fail to be continuous hence analytic where those half-lines intersect $D$ so Cauchy cannot be applied to the usual $D'$ where we take out zeroes only in $D$ as half-lines coming from the right of $D$ (and corresponding to zeroes outside $D$) may well intersect it as noted; there is a very good reason that in the RZ theory, Littlewood lemma is applied on rectangles that start on $\sigma =2$ as in the  Gonek reference provided by @Stopple

Comment: @Conrad My $D$ is also starting at $\sigma=2$ and I am starting the logarithm of zeta at $\sigma=2$.

Comment: Write it down for a simple function $f(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$ , where $z_1=1/2+i\tau$ is in your domain and $z_2=3/4+i\tau$ is not but the half line that starts at $z_2$ and goes left intersects your domain; that will clarify what happens (you will pick up a trace of $z_2$ however you define your logarithm st is analytic on D minus a segment from $z_1$ )

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. I am sorry I can't understand that $z_2$ is not in your domain "but the half line that starts at $z_2$ and goes left intersects my domain." Why do we want a half line that starts at $z_2$ and goes left to intersect my domain?

Comment: Because that will have $z_2$ leaving a trace in littlewood lemma even though $z_2$ is not in your domain - for the zeta function this means that zeroes in the critical strip but not in your domain will also influence the result in a way or another (this could be direct by jumps hence discontinuities in the logarithm or indirect by the definition of the logarithm which will differ from the standard one precisely by $2\pi i$ multiples of those outside zeroes

Comment: @Conrad I am sorry, I cannot understand that how will the zeroes in the critical strip but not in my domain will influence the result.

Comment: Because if you define the logarithm of zeta the standard way like in Titchmarsh etc then those zeroes will give discontinuities in your domain that have to be accounted for; if you define it differently so it is continuous on your domain minus the segments from littlewood lemma, the logarithm will differ from the standard one by $2\pi i$ multiples of the missing zeroes so when you integrate it those will appear in the result

Comment: The limiting process makes the logarithm discontinuous from up vs down by $2\pi i$

Comment: By the argument principle applied to the domain consisting essentially of the big rectangle from $2$ to $1/2-\epsilon$ minus your $D$ which on one hand counts the zeroes not in your $D$ and on the other expresses the difference between the Titchmarsh logarithm and yours on the edges of $D$; this is of course a bit vague but it should be fairly intuitive when you draw a picture

Comment: @Conrad Please write a detailed answer. With utmost respect I will accept it.